# High Usage of Non Paged Memory on Windows Server 2016

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2016, memory-usage

Good day, 
I have been trying to troubleshoot a high non paged memory error from Solarwinds Remote Monitoring Management software it reports 664mb non paged usage on the Host OS and 145mb non paged usage on the Virtual Machine. My basic understanding is that such an error occurs when a driver attempts to access memory reserved for windows. The poolmon program shows the Mdl and Irp tags as having the highest memory usage however when I do a search using findstr I get over 150 results initially attempted to install missing chipset drivers, a driver for the storage card, The Network interface card and updated the BIOS however the error still persists. I am not sure which driver to update to resolve this error. Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Specifications of Server

Dell Poweredge T440

RAM: 49GB ECC
Processor: Intel(R) Xeon(R) Silver 4114  x 2
Storage: DELL PERC H330 Adp SCSI Disk Device 4TB
OS: Windows Server 2016

Virtual Machine

Ram: 16 GB
Storage: 500 GB
OS: Windows Server 2012

Poolmon report

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MO2gd.png

Memory Performance

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFYfx.png

Comment: `664mb non paged usage on the Host OS and 145mb non paged usage on the Virtual Machine`. That seems normal to me.

Comment: I guess i should just adjust the Monitoring tool then.